# Safari returns "invalid date" when parsing a YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS+0000 ISO time string

Tags: javascript, date, testing, safari

The API I am using, returns dates in a format like `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS+0200`. When I try to create a `Date` object of that, it usually works:

```js
new Date('2021-06-28T12:00:00+0200');
```

However, some users with an older version of Safari/iOS complain, that they get some "Invalid Date", which I cannot recreate because all my devices are up to date.

1. How can I fix the date parsing so that it works across all browsers? Is the date string incorrect? Is the parsing incorrect?
2. How can I test if it actually does? Because as I said, it already seems to be working on alle the devices I have access to, but unfortunately it doesn’t on some devices I don’t have access to...

Thank you very much!

Comment: According to the [specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-date-time-string-format) the format is not "valid". The UTC offset has to be in the format `hh:mm` and not `hhmm`

Comment: _"...so that it works across all browsers?"_ - Use a specialized library for date stuff.

Comment: The format is a valid ISO 8601 string however, since UTC offsets may be specified in the form ±[hh]:[mm], ±[hh][mm], or ±[hh].

Comment: @Andreas yes, thank you! If the input string would be in the format `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS+02:00` (`+HH:MM`) it would work. I’ll check out a way to fix the input before parsing as I don't want to use a library just for that.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using a library such as [luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/) for parsing dates. It should handle both `+hhmm` and `+hh:mm` UTC offsets.

You can parse to a luxon DateTime, then simply call `.toJSDate()` to get a Date, this should mean minimal code changes:

```js
let { DateTime } = luxon;

console.log("Using +hhmm UTC offset:");
let input = '2021-06-28T12:00:00+0200';
let d = (DateTime.fromISO(input));
console.log('Input:', input)
console.log('toJSDate:', d.toJSDate())
console.log('ISO time (Local):', d.toISO())

console.log("\nUsing +hh:mm UTC offset:");
input = '2021-06-28T12:00:00+02:00';
d = (DateTime.fromISO(input));
console.log('Input:', input)
console.log('toJSDate:', d.toJSDate())
console.log('ISO time (Local):', d.toISO())
```

```html
<script src="https://moment.github.io/luxon/global/luxon.js"></script>
```

Comment: Why is an opinion-based recommendation of a library an answer?

Comment: Criticism noted Andreas, I do believe in this instance a date/time library is very beneficial, and we have do have to pick one.